# How to fix access denied, youtube-dl updater

Tags: python, pyinstaller, youtube-dl

I'm building a chat program including youtube-dl for music streaming, everything works except when it's not updated, so I set out to use the update_self function of youtube-dl for auto-update with no success.

The program is built on windows 7 with Python 3.6, youtube-dl from pip install(I get an error for that but it goes away once compilled), I used Pyinstaller to build the exe. the code is supposed to basically check for and update ytdl if needed however it seems to be waiting for some file to close and then throw an error.

All is done with this one line pointing to [update.py](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/update.py) of ytdl.

```
youtube_dl.update_self(self.ytdl_popup, False, youtube_dl.YoutubeDL()._opener)
```

ytdl_popup is just to display update messages to the screen and shouldn't matter.

[Error Picture](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/294143904461094912/610239375959261186/unknown.png)

Unlike what is displayed, ytdl isn't actually updated by this.

Sorry in advance if I'm missing something obvious, and thanks in advance to those who will answer.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: how do you check if it did not update? Chances are it already updated once and you can update the same application severally unless there is an actual update. Maybe you already have the newest version that is why nothing changes.

Comment: I compiled the program with an outdated ytdl on purpose to test this, and I had a link that didn't work unless updated so I could test it in practice too. 
After several testing my thoughts were that ytdl was buried in the exe and that was what causing the problem of write access.

Comment: The check to see if it's up to date was also displaying properly in ytdl popup if I used an updated version, so it's really the updating process that was screwed up.